# How do I scatter icons all over a background randomly?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background

I've been wondering this a time now but I just saw a background like this on dribbble. I want to have multiple icons scattered across a background with random position and random rotation using Illustrator could someone possibly point me into the right  direction?

link to the dribble example: https://dribbble.com/shots/1744511-Splash-Sign-up-and-Tutorial-screens/attachments/282439

Comment: That's very clearly NOT random at all. Its a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a pattern main steps.

1. Make your bunch of icons which you want to be repeated.
2. Go object > pattern > make
3. make modifications that you want (overlap, tile type etc.)
4. under file name click done
5. you can find it in swatches panel.